# Is it simply Cleaning or Refactoring?

Tags: project-structure

I am working on a project in C++, and I have a big CPP file with several functions in it. I am actually working on splitting all these functions into smaller cpp files to make it more readable. I was wondering if this process had actually a name? I was thinking about calling it "Refactoring", but this process seems more complicated than my "little" work.

This is a simple example of what I am doing:

Coming from FileA.cpp:

```
extern "C"
{
    namespace foo
    {
        functionA()
        {
            //Some Code
        }
        functionB()
        {
            //Some Code
        }
        .
        .
        .
        functionZ()
        {
             // Some Code
        }
    }
}
```

To FileB.cpp

```
extern "C"
{
    namespace foo
    {
        functionA()
        {
            // Some Code
        }
        functionB()
        {
            // Some Code
        }
    }
}
```

FileC.cpp

```
extern "C"
{
    namespace foo
    {
        functionC()
        {
            // Some Code
        }
        functionD()
        {
            // Some Code
        }
    }
}
```

etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean OOP-Design: How to implement single responsibility and no procedural programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/323661/clean-oop-design-how-to-implement-single-responsibility-and-no-procedural-progr)

Comment: see also: [How to determine if a class meets the single responsibility principle?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/154723/31260)

Comment: Why is the file so large? Is it trying to do too many things?. Since this is C++ is it worth considering breaking up a large class?

Comment: You're right, but my source file is not a class at all. At the begining, I was working with a class with static functions only, and by the time I though it was useless to do that so now it's only a namespace with several functions in it and all the others "child" sources files are part of this namespace.
I will edit again my message to be clearer.

Comment: Is there much "global" data? If groups of functions share data consider making them into a class (this is assuming you want an OO design)

Comment: If its C (some C++ is really just C code) consider breaking out libraries or even ADTs.

Comment: @NickKeighley Sorry for my late answer.
There is no Global Data, they do not share any data.
Actually it's C++ code but as you said, my code has a strong C component.
My work is to make a DLL made of functions called by another program, written in another language. There are classes in this other program and their functions are just calling their "twin" from my DLL to do their work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people might use the term "refactoring" for what you described, however, Martin Fowler, who invented the term, published a [catalog](https://refactoring.com/catalog/) of typical refactorings. Splitting a big CPP file into smaller ones, by distributing the classes and functions to different files (without changing any of the functions) - is not in that catalogue.

The refactorings Fowler describes are *logical* cleanups, where, for example, functions with more than one responsibility are reworked and divided into functions with just one responsibility. This is opposed to *physical* cleanups, where the functions themselves stay the same, only the CPP file (the "physical place") where one finds the function's source code changes. So if you are doing the first, it is clearly refactoring, but if it is the latter, then I think the term "cleaning" fits better.

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain what is the difference between logical and physical cleanups ?

Comment: @Freddykong: see my edit

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the term "refactoring" will apply here. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring#List_of_refactoring_techniques

> - Techniques for breaking code apart into more logical pieces
>     ...
>
>   - Extract Method, to turn part of a larger method into a new method. By breaking down code in smaller pieces, it is more easily understandable. This is also applicable to functions.

---

**UPDATE**

Now that the question has been updated and clarified, I would agree with [Doc Brown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/347708/13156) and say that "clean-up" is probably a better term for this activity than "refactoring".

Comment: The way the OP describes it does not sound like he is *"turning parts of a larger method into a new method"* - it sounds like he is only moving unchanged methods from one source file into another.

Comment: You're right @DocBrown , I made an example to be more understandable

Comment: @Freddykong: Thanks for the example. Yes, that changes the meaning of the question, and now I need to update my answer.